# Can I run StarCraft: Broodwar on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, alternative

Im currently running Mavericks on my MacBookPro (Late 2008) and want to get a different OS that will run Starcraft 1: Broodwar, WITHOUT using wine.

Comment: What's the problem about Wine? If you go through PlayOnLinux it isn't half as bad to configure. Especially when there is a scripted installation like for "StarCraft: Broodwar"

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

No, not natively.

The longer answer is:

Yes you should be able to configure WINE or VMBox to be able to play any game that runs on Windows by emulating windows. You will also need to ensure your graphic drivers are updated to the best available.

Edit: I didn't read the part about 'not going through WINE'